# Command already defined but also undefined

Tags: macros, undefined

I used `\input{settings.tex}` to inlcude my settings file which contains `\newcommand{\ende}{20:00}`. If I try to build the project I get this error: `Command \ende already defined.`
If I try to use `\renewcommand{\ende}{20:00}` to redefine the command I get the error: `Command \ende undefined.`. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 7):

You should read the *whole* error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ende already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

In your case the relevant bit is the second line. Macros starting with `\end...` are reserved for the closing code of environments: `\newcommand` checks 1) whether the macro isn't already defined and 2) that it does not start with `\end...`, but doesn't discriminate the two cases in the ensuing error message.

If you really must use that name you can use the low-level TeX construction

```
\def\ende{20:00}
```

but I'd suggest to choose a different name

```
\newcommand*{\Ende}{20:00}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that in LaTeX the macro `\ende` is considered the ending-macro of the `e`-environment in case the macro `\e` is defined "by hand" and afterwards invoked via `\begin{e}...\end{e}`.

Currently (August 2022) you cannot `\newcommand` but you can `\renewcommand` commands whose name is "illegal".

If you insist in defining a command whose name is "illegal" due to starting with `\end...`  so that attempts at defining yield the same behavior as attempts at defining commands in terms of `\newcommand` whose name is not "illegal", you can try s.th. like this:

```latex
% When you uncomment the next but one line, then \ende is defined and
% the subsequent construct yields an error-message.
%\def\ende{\texttt{\string\ende}\space is defined}

\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{ende}%
{\def\ende{}\csname @firstoftwo\endcsname\renewcommand}{}%
\newcommand\ende{20:00}
```

In case you like to have this as a macro, you can do s.th. like this:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\newcommandwithendallowed{%
  \@star@or@long\newcommand@withendallowed
}%
\newcommand\newcommand@withendallowed[1]{%
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1
  \@ifundefined{\string#1}%
  {\endgroup\def#1{}\renew@command}%
  {\endgroup\new@command}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

% When you uncomment the next but one line, then \ende is defined and
% the subsequent construct yields an error-message.
%\def\ende{\texttt{\string\ende}\space is defined}

\newcommandwithendallowed*\ende[0]{20:00}

\show\ende

\stop
```

**A better way of circumventing the problem is defining things in terms of `\NewDocumentCommand` or the like which comes along with the package xparse and which also comes along with more recent LaTeX 2ε-releases.**